# How to Fill Color in A cell in Workbook_BeforeSave

Tags: vba, excel

I currently have this code below:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Select

For i = 2 To 10
    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value = "YES" Then
        For j = 2 To 5
            If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, j).Value = "" Then
                **<insert format here>**
            End If
        Next j
    End If


    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value = "NO" Then
        For j = 2 To 5
            If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, j).Value = "" Then
                **<insert format here>**
            End If
        Next j
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Now. I tried to add the code below inside the If statement but didn't worked

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, j).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
```

How can we add fill color to the cells without value?

Comment: You realize, that you are checking ANSI X12 and you are adding to Sheet1?

Comment: What was the error?

Comment: @Vityata I've updated the code :) sorry for the typo

Comment: @Nathan_Sav Application-defined or object-defined error

Comment: and the error is where the **< line is?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav yes after the If statement

Comment: you can use `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, j).Interior.Color = vbGreen` but then you are limited to the colors VB keeps.

Answer (score 2):

`Interior.ColorIndex` must work on range

maybe is the logic that doesn't work as expected

try this

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim i As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        For i = 2 To 10
            Select Case .Cells(i, 1).value
                Case "YES"
                    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells(i, 2).Resize(, 4)) < 4 Then .Cells(i, 2).Resize(, 4).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                Case "NO"
                    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells(i, 2).Resize(, 4)) < 4 Then .Cells(i, 2).Resize(, 4).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Interior.ColorIndex = 2
            End Select
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @PeterS, did you get through it?

Comment: @PeterS, it'd be nice from you to give feedback to people trying at helping you

Comment: @PeterS, I see you keep asking in SO. It's fine. It'd be fine you answer, too. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this one (before save):

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tabelle1").Cells(1, 1).Select

    For i = 2 To 10
        If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tabelle1").Cells(i, 1).Value = "YES" Then
            For j = 2 To 5
                If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tabelle1").Cells(i, j).Value = "" Then
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tabelle1").Cells(i, j).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                    '**<insert format here>**
                End If
            Next j
        End If


        If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tabelle1").Cells(i, 1).Value = "" Then
            For j = 2 To 5
                If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tabelle1").Cells(i, j).Value = "" Then
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tabelle1").Cells(i, j).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                    '**<insert format here>**
                End If
            Next j
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: In this line "ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, j).Interior.ColorIndex = 3"

Comment: write >debug.Print ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Main").cells(i,j).address< before it.

Comment: Yup. It works. I have changed the code. Just make sure you do not have "Option Explicit" anywhere on top. Because it is not exactly "high quality" code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117187/discussion-between-peters-and-vityata).

Comment: I dont know why it's not working on me :( we almost have the same code right? Or I missed something different on your code?

Comment: Yup. No idea. Probably something with the text/value. Can you open a completely new Excel file and write my code there? Just change "Tabelle1" to "sheet1".

Comment: it's working on the new excel file. Do you have any idea why it's not working on my excel file? I have a current feature in Sheet1 wherein we have to fill the cell with green for mandatory cells and remove this fill when cell value != NULL

Comment: No idea, really. Have you tried the debug.print from my second comment here?